# Использование функций до объявления

Tags: sql-server, sql

Есть рабочий скрипт для ms sql server 2008. И я его не могу запустить, потому что триггеры используют функции, которые описаны позже, чем сами триггеры. Как заставить его работать?

Comment: Переставить объявление функций до объявления триггеров. Ваш кэп.

Comment: править скрипт и тысяч строк дело не только трудоемкое, но и не в моих правах.

Comment: А каким же образом он работал до этого?

Comment: Работал не у меня.

Answer (score 1):

Есть подозрение, что у MS нет такой опции. Во всяком случае тут http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686.aspx о ней ни слова.
На твоем месте я бы: 1. посоздавал пустые функции, необходимые триггерам (их заголовки придется вытащить из скрипта). 2. Соответственно, create func заменил на alter func (Ctrl+H на скрипт). 3. Накат скрипта. Все объекты будут найдены.